# How can I restrict a Jenkins declarative pipeline job to run on related nodes?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline job that runs on three nodes.  The first node is the master, so it's not pertinent to my question.  The other two nodes are actually the same machine on which I have two agents.  One of those agents (named 'Win10-E-Admin') runs as an Administrator, the other agent (named 'Win10-E-Normal') runs as a normal logged-in user.  This is so that I can do things like install a package, but then test it as a normal user.

So, the question is:  How can I force this pipeline job to run only on nodes that belong to the same machine?  In other words, I want to tell the job to go ahead and run on any Win10 node, but once it has started on a specific node, then all its *-Admin and *-Normal steps need to stay on that same machine?

Example pipeline:

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('Kill Edge') {
        agent { label 'rk-Win10-E-Normal' }
        steps {
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
            bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        }    
    }
    stage("Start Timestamp") {
        agent { label 'rk-Win10-E-Admin' }
        steps {
            bat (script: '"C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe" "Needed files\\Scripts\\CreateStartTimestamp.py"')
        }    
    }
    stage('Activate Edge') {
        agent { label 'rk-Win10-E-Normal' }
        steps {
            bat "start microsoft-edge:http://www.cnn.com"
        }    
    }
    stage('With Edge Running') {
        agent { label 'rk-Win10-E-Admin' }
        steps {
            bat (script: "some_command_that_needs_to_be_run_as_administrator_and_needs_Edge.exe")
        }    
    }
}
}
```

So, to explain--You'll notice that I've specified which of my machines I want to run this on (rk-Win10-E) and which agent to use (-Normal or -Admin).
What I want to do is, instead of specifying the machine, I just want to specify (using labels) to run on a machine that has Edge and Python.  But from what I understand, when Jenkins gets to the agent line, it'll pick any of my machines that provide Edge and Python, so there's no guarantee that the last parts of my pipeline will work, since it might pick an entirely different machine to run the later commands on.

My question then is, after the first agent call, is there a way for the script to find out what agent is being used, then use string manipulations to get the name of the -Admin node that corresponds to the -Normal node that was originally used?

Comment: Please post a sample of your pipeline after removing any sensitive information so that it is easier to understand your workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is actually not too hard to do.  I used a script call to set the names, then used those names in the future blocks.  So the modified pipeline looks like this:

```
windowsAdminNode = 'temp'
windowsNormalNode = 'temp'

pipeline {
agent none
stages {
stage('Kill Edge') {
    agent { label 'Win10' && 'Python' }
    steps {
        script {
            windowsNormalNode = NODE_NAME
            windowsAdminNode = windowsNormalNode.minus('-Normal').plus('-Admin')
        }
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
        bat (script: "taskkill /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe > NUL 2>&1", returnStatus: true)
    }    
}
stage("Start Timestamp") {
    agent { node windowsAdminNode }
    steps {
        bat (script: '"C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe" "Needed files\\Scripts\\CreateStartTimestamp.py"')
    }    
}
stage('Activate Edge') {
    agent { node windowsNormalNode }
    steps {
        bat "start microsoft-edge:http://www.cnn.com"
    }    
}
stage('With Edge Running') {
    agent { node windowsAdminNode }
    steps {
        bat (script: "some_command_that_needs_to_be_run_as_administrator_and_needs_Edge.exe")
    }    
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//here node or agent name is "tomcat_server"
pipeline {
agent none

```
    stages {
       stage('Build') {
           agent { label 'tomcat_server' }
           steps {
               echo "This is my  build pipeline project"
           }
       } 
        stage('test') {
           agent { label 'tomcat_server' }
           steps {
               echo "This is my  test pipeline project"
           }
       } 
        stage('deploy') {
           agent { label 'tomcat_server' }
           steps {
               echo "This is my  deploy pipeline project"
           }
       } 
    }
```

}